# How to Compile Opencv3.2.0 with opencv_contrib

Tags: c++, linux, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I use Centos7 and gcc is 4.8.5.I can not Comple extra modules from opencv_contrib like xfeatures2d for opencv3.2.0. I used
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../modules/opencv_contrib-3.x.x/modules Flag But I just get some errors like 
opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:340:5: error: ‘hal’  has not been declared
Would you please help me how to install Opencv3.2 with xfeatures2d.

Comment: Why are you using contrib modules for 3.0.0? [Use contrib for 3.2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)

Comment: Because I want to use "SurfFeatureDetector" and "SurfDescriptorExtractor "objects

Comment: Yes, but you're compiling the **wrong** contrib. You need to use the one for your OpenCV version!

Comment: I tested opencv_contrib 3.2.0 & 3.2.0-rc & 3.1.0 & 3.0.0 All of them get to error   :(     my job is in danger

Comment: I'm sorry,  but I never got a problem while compiling the correct version. So I cannot help you. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem . You can Download opencv3.2.0 and opencv_contrib3.2.0 
Then use -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/modules  Flag to add opencv_contrib to the opencv. The problem is the some files in repositories have incorrect md5.you should download it manually from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/commit/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d and Copy it to itself folder. then Compile it again.

Comment: Any one please can upload it compiled so we can use it ? and don't get troubles with this compiling process ?